# Unit testing a generic base Controller using Moq and Xunit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, moq, xunit.net

I currently have a base class like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractControllerBase<T> : Controller where T : AbstractControllerBase<T>
{
    private ILogger<T> _logger;

    protected ILogger<T> Logger => _logger ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<T>>();

    public AbstractControllerBase()
    { }
}
```

and inherited class like this:

```
public abstract class ControllerBase<T> : AbstractControllerBase<T> where T : ControllerBase<T>
{
    private IRepository _repository;

    protected IRepository Repository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_repository == null && HttpContext != null)
                _repository = (IRepository)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IRepository));
            return _repository;
        }
    }

    public ControllerBase()
    { }

    public IActionResult CheckRedirectUrl(string url)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(url))
        {
            var redirectResult = Redirect(url);
            return redirectResult;
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

There are 25 controllers which inherit from ControllerBase. How to init Repository while unit testing. I tried doing this:

```
if (controller is Website.Controllers.ControllerBase < typeof(controller) >)
{
    ((Website.Controllers.ControllerBase)controller).Repository = repository;
}
```

But this requires generic arguments as well. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can’t access protected members outside of derived classes. You also can’t mock them if the protected member isn’t virtual. The member must at least be virtual to allow Moq framework to override the member:

```
protected virtual IRepository Repository
{
    get
    {
        if (_repository == null && HttpContext != null)
            _repository = (IRepository)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IRepository));
        return _repository;
    }
}
```

When you have a virtual property, you can mock it:

```
var mock = new Mock<MyController>();    // MyController inherits from ControllerBase
mock.Protected().SetupGet<IRepository>("Repository").Returns(new RepositoryMock()); // RepositoryMock implements IRepository
```

Although I would recommend injecting the repository dependency as a parameter of the constructor. This would not require mocking protected members, as you simply inject the mocked repository as a parameter.